# Raspberry Pi B+ not visible on Windows Workgroup

Tags: networking, archlinux, samba

I have Raspberry Pi B+, connected to LAN and I can communicate with WAN without any problems. However, I've installed Samba using following configuration (smb.conf):

```
#======================= Global Settings =====================================
[global]

# workgroup = NT-Domain-Name or Workgroup-Name
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   security = user
   map to guest = Bad User

#============================ Share Definitions ==============================
[measurements]
   comment = Pidaq Measurements Folder
   browseable = yes
   writable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   path = /mnt/data
```

The rPi B+ gets IP, I can ping it on LAN, I can logon via SSH, but I cannot see the share on network. The `/mnt/data` partition configration has been dounble checked and works ok. I am using Archlinux and now I can see it in Windows Explorer, but If I click on it, I get following Windows 7 error:[image: Cannot access Samba Share]

Comment: did you try accessing by IP i.e.: \\<ip_address>\measurements\

Comment: Is the computer set to discover network shares? (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings) - check that discovery is turned on and that file and printer sharing is also turned on for whichever network you are on.

Comment: have you restarted samba? or rebooted the pi? is samba running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved! I've added `umask=022` to shared folder description, restared samba and now it works.